# high performance tcp server in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, tcp, publish-subscribe

I've seen many good tcp-based projects in other languages, for example C/C++.

Is there any good one in Node.js? I'm implementing a tcp-based real-time pub/sub system using Node.js, but have some problems when high pressure.

I don't really need those simple tcp server examples or baby-steps tutorials. **I need some real projects.**

Thanks!

EDIT:

I write a chat-like node.js program to exchange data from clients. It's pretty good when I test it with only few people.

However, when more people, like hundreds people, join in, it starts to loss data. Check out this: [How to deal with 'read ETIMEDOUT' in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972106/how-to-deal-with-read-etimedout-in-node-js).

The answer is good but cannot help on improving the stability.

I don't really expect people who dive into my dirty codes to find my errors. That's why I want some real projects to see how they do.

Comment: What problems?
What kind of high pressure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this [reading material](http://konklone.com/post/the-making-of-isitchristmas-dot-com-2012) might help you.
In his case, he was broadcasting mouse events to several clients. And the amount of data to publish was so great that he had to cluster users by "rooms"